# Why is sub2ind populating my array with only one value?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

The goal of this block of code is to relate each value of vm to a corresponding value in Y.

```
values = zeros(5090,1000); 
for i = 1:1000
    voltFile_number = i; 
    vm = grab3dVoltPG(voltpath, voltFile_number);
   %go to 2D, grab the point to find in 2D
    for q = 1:2
       for j = 1:5090
        Ind = sub2ind(size(Y), j, q);
            for k =1:10180
            values(j,i) = Y(k);
           end
        end 
    end
end
```

It keeps pulling just one value, the same value, from vm or Y to populate values.

Comment: In your loop over `k`, you are assigning to the *same* index `(j,i)` of values first `Y(1)`, then `Y(2)`, always ending with `Y(10180)`. That is why every element of `values` is equal to `Y(10180)`.

Comment: Your question title is about sub2ind. But you never actually use it.  You assign the output of sub2ind to `Ind` however `Ind` is never used in your loop.

Comment: I guess you wanted to write `values(j,i) = Y(ind);` But you have to remove the loop over k. When I understand your questions correctly this should produce the expected result.